# Change width of the Validation error message div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[image]

This is how the error message is getting displayed once the validations are added. It only takes the width of that div. How can I change the width so the error message fits a single line? If there's any other way to do front-end validations please suggest it.

```css
.age {
  width: 53px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.input-group {
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  position: relative;
}

.input-group__label {
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #aaa;
  left: 5px;
  padding: 0 7px;
  transition: line-height 200ms ease-in-out, font-size 200ms ease-in-out, top 200ms ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.input-group__input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 4px !important;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group age">
                    <input class="input-group__input form-control is-invalid"
                           type="text"
                           placeholder="&nbsp;"
                           name="age"
                           id="validationError"
                           autocomplete="off"
                           required />
                    <label class="input-group__label" for="age">Age</label>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter an age between 35-74
                      years.
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: the error panel doesn't have a width. You could add a width in the .age ruleset like `width: 100%` and it will the take the size enough to contain everything in one line.

Comment: @diegod That's the thing. I can't change the .age width. It should be that width.

Comment: .invalid-feedback{ width: max-content;}

Comment: @JaswinderKaur position of the element requires to be absolute, in order for this to work.
while will lead to overlap from other elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really change the width of your `invalid-feedback` element because it's max width is being controlled by its parent `input-group age`. I'd suggest removing the `age` class and instead apply it to its first two children, minus its third child `invalid-feedback`.

**Note:** I also increased the max width of the `age` class, otherwise the validation icons' are obtruding the view of the validation text due to lack of space.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
    .age {
        max-width: 96px;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 16px;
        letter-spacing: 0.15px;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    }
    .input-group {
        margin-bottom: 9px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .input-group__label {
        z-index: 5;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        line-height: 40px;
        color: #aaa;
        left: 5px;
        padding: 0 7px;
        transition: line-height 200ms ease-in-out, font-size 200ms ease-in-out, top 200ms ease-in-out;
        pointer-events: none;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 16px;
        letter-spacing: 0.15px;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    }
    .input-group__input {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        border-radius: 4px !important;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
</style>
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="age input-group__input form-control is-invalid"
         type="text"
         placeholder="&nbsp;"
         name="age"
         id="validationError"
         autocomplete="off"
         required />
  <label class="age input-group__label" for="age">Age</label>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">
    Please enter an age between 35-74 years.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works. But the elements next to it get affected. But I can look into that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the invalid-feedback block to max-content.

The max-content sizing keyword represents the maximum width or height of the content. For text content, this means that the content will not wrap at all even if it causes overflows.

```
.invalid-feedback{
  width: max-content;
}
```

Here's the MDN page on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content

Answer (score 0):

You can make "input-group" "position: relative" and add to "invalid-feedback" "position: absolute, width: max-content"

Absolute position to make it at a higher level than what would be below

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-colden-zg3let?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: If you use the code snippet, then its easier to verify your answer.  When editing, its the button with **<>**

Comment: I don't now how use snippet, just sandbox

Comment: Next time you are entering a question or editing it look for the button with **<>** on it

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by simply adding a width value to the label.

```
.invalid-feedback {
    width: 250px; /* OR max-content */
}
```